# Why does creating a loop on my button make my android app hang?

Tags: android, loops, button, dictionary

I am writing an Android location based app. For my app i need to store my current location for every fixed time period. I create a button to start store those location using loop, but in device it hangs when start. If i remove the loop, it works. Whats the problem?

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {

    GoogleMap googleMap;

    Button btnStart,btnStop, btnstatus;
    double fLat,fLon,sLat,sLon;

    ArrayList<LatLng> locArray=new ArrayList<LatLng>();    

    int var,i;

    double lat=0, lon=0;
    LatLng fLL,sLL;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnStart=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
        btnStop=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
        btnstatus=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStatus);


        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                for(i=1;;i++)
                {
                    Location loc=googleMap.getMyLocation();

                    double lat=loc.getLatitude();
                    double lon=loc.getLongitude();

                    LatLng latLon=new LatLng(lat, lon);
                    locArray.add(latLon);
                }

            }


        });

        btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

           for(i=1;i<locArray.size();i++)
                {
                    LatLng src=locArray.get(i-1);
                    LatLng dest=locArray.get(i);

                    googleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().add(new LatLng(src.latitude, src.longitude),new LatLng(dest.latitude, dest.longitude)).width(3).color(Color.RED).geodesic(true));
                }
            }
        });


        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment=(SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        googleMap=supportMapFragment.getMap();

        //googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        // googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
        // googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
        // googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);


        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {


        Location loc=googleMap.getMyLocation();

        double latitude=loc.getLatitude();
        double longitude=loc.getLongitude();



        LatLng latLon=new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLon));
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLon));
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));


    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


}
```

And here is my Button XML:

Comment: Why u havnt limit you loop?? it seems would run infinite time...

Answer (score 1):

You have an endless for loop in the btnStart:

```
for (i = 1;; i++)
```

Why do you have a loop there? There is only one location anyway. Just remove the for loop and leave the internal code.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Location loc = googleMap.getMyLocation();

    double lat = loc.getLatitude();
    double lon = loc.getLongitude();

    LatLng latLon = new LatLng(lat, lon);
    locArray.add(latLon);
}
```

Comment: i need to store my every location for every fixed time period, so why i need a loop. i am facing same problem when i use while loop, and set a  in  condition btnStop button like (int v=1) and (int v=0 in button Start) and while(v=1){}

Answer (score 0):

your endless loop blocks UI thread will cause ANR :

```
for(i=1;;i++)
```

Comment: i need to store my every location for every fixed time period, so why i need a loop. i am facing same problem when i use while loop, and set a in condition btnStop button like (int v=1) and (int v=0 in button Start) and while(v=1){}

Comment: do your work on another thread , using AsyncTask or a Service . Never do a long operator on UI Thread.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set the condition for quitting the loop.

```
for (i = 1; ; i++)
```

for loop is

```
for (initialize to start loop; condition to stop loop; increment/decrement) {
    // body of loop
}
```

just because you haven't put the condition when to stop,
that's why you are getting an error.

Comment: i need to store my every location for every fixed time period, so why i need a loop. i am facing same problem when i use while loop, and set a in condition btnStop button like (int v=1) and (int v=0 in button Start) and while(v=1){}

Answer (score 0):

You can use single `boolean` variable to decide *where to start* and *where to stop* fetching the locations from providers

This is example, variable is `isStartedFetching`

```
    private boolean isStartedFetching = false;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnStart=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
        btnStop=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
        btnstatus=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStatus);


        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                isStartedFetching = true;
                /* for(i=1;;i++)  // this is infinite loop, so application will hang
                {
                    Location loc=googleMap.getMyLocation();

                    double lat=loc.getLatitude();
                    double lon=loc.getLongitude();

                    LatLng latLon=new LatLng(lat, lon);
                    locArray.add(latLon);
                }

            } */


        });

        btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            isStartedFetching = false;
           for(i=1;i<locArray.size();i++)
                {
                    LatLng src=locArray.get(i-1);
                    LatLng dest=locArray.get(i);

                    googleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().add(new LatLng(src.latitude, src.longitude),new LatLng(dest.latitude, dest.longitude)).width(3).color(Color.RED).geodesic(true));
                }
            }
        });


        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment=(SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        googleMap=supportMapFragment.getMap();

        //googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        // googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
        // googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
        // googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);


        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        if(isStartedFetching) {
        Location loc=googleMap.getMyLocation();

        double latitude=loc.getLatitude();
        double longitude=loc.getLongitude();



        LatLng latLon=new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLon));
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLon));
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
        }

    }
```